# How to disable sms on particular speed(acclerometer) in android

Tags: android

I want to create app on which user can not open sms when he is driving car(mean by checking accelerometer on particular  speed of android device).Is it possible in android and if yes then how we can do that.Thanks..
Nishant Jain

Comment: I'm intrigued. Why do you want to do this? Driver safety?

Comment: BTW nice innovative thinking.. instead you can try one more thing.. if the person crosses 60 km/hr of speed.. sms his speed to his parents..!! :D

Comment: I like the idea! Perhaps you can just warn the user that texting while driving (moving at the speed grater than say 7mph) is dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

The accelerometer measures acceleration, not speed. Since you tend to only gently accelerate or decelerate when driving, and even then most of the time you're travelling at constant speed, it's probably not possible to do this with the accelerometer.

It is probably possible to do something like this using the GPS and checking how quickly the person is currently moving by checking for changes in that, but the battery use would be massive. Even doing that, I'm not sure if Android apps can actually suspend other apps from running in any useful way.

In short, I don't think this is practical. Sorry!

Comment: Agreed. Also not to mention the fact that it would also disable SMS while you are a passenger with someone else, or on a bus, etc.

It's a clever idea, but there are a lot of variables. Better option I would think would be a simple Enable/Disable widget on the home screen that the user can select before driving.